# How can I make the navigation work in my project in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a split view (hamburger menu). The main page is divided into 2 columns. The first one is just split view and the second one contains a frame. I'd like to be able to change the contents of the frame depending on which button in the menu is clicked. Is it possible to do this way?

Comment: actually you can do this by adding a frame element in your page, then load different page on that frame so, your main page split view will always there only frame will change through loading different pages. e.g you have home button and another is settings button son when you click on any button your frame will load respective navigated page on frame you can follow this 33rd to 36th video of this series https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541?l=VgkAjDCrB_2005244527

Comment: Glad it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do this by adding a frame element in your page, then load different page on that frame so, your main page split view will always there only frame will change through loading different pages.

e.g you have home button and another is settings button so when you click on any button your frame will load respective navigated page on frame you can follow this 33rd to 36th video of this series

you should add this element

```
<Frame Name="MyFrame"></Frame>
```

to load your page on it without fully navigating to other pages like this.

```
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourPage));
```